# Is there a way to interpolate from a table with data in scipy?

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation

My question is the following. I have a code that computes, for a given x, a value of a function f(x). However since f(x) is a bit too large and complicated, and the program has to go through a very large dataset (x) at different timesteps, is not really efficient. I was wondering if there is a function maybe in scipy, so that I can create a table with different already computed values for f(x), something like save in a file "function.txt" a table like (of course in my case the table will be larger going from values 1e0, 1e8):

```
x    f(x)
1     1 
2     4 
3     9
4     16 
5     25
```

And then somehow use an interpolation, such that if my program reads that x = 2.2 it can estimate the value f(x) from the already calculated values in the table.

Comment: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp1d.html

Answer (score 1):

I could actually do what I wanted in a very simple way using interp1d. To give an example using the numbers I used before.

```
import numpy
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d

x = numpy.linspace(1, 100, 1000)
y = x**2

f = interp1d(x, y)
xnew = 2.2
ynew = f(x)

print f(x)
```

The output: 4.84095446798

Answer (score 0):

You have polyfit and polyval in numpy :

```
import numpy as np

x=np.arange(1,6)
y=np.array((1,4,9,16,25))
coeffs=np.polyfit(x,y,deg=5) # eval your polynomial coefficients
x2=np.linspace(np.min(x),np.max(x),1000)
y2=np.polyval(coeffs,x2) # apply your polynomial coeff to a broader set of data
```